# mysql_real_escape_string does it allow no quotes within a sql query?

Tags: php

Is this code buggy?

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['Submit'])) {

    // Retrieve data

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

    $getid = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = $id";

    $result = mysql_query($getid) or die('<pre>' . mysql_error() . '</pre>' );

    $num = mysql_numrows($result);

    $i=0;

    while ($i < $num) {

        $first = mysql_result($result,$i,"first_name");
        $last = mysql_result($result,$i,"last_name");

        echo '<pre>';
        echo 'ID: ' . $id . '<br>First name: ' . $first . '<br>Surname: ' . $last;
        echo '</pre>';

        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

Despite the fact that it uses mysql_real_escape_string , an attacker can still inject code without quotes.

It's part of DVWA vulnerable web application.

Does the function mysql_real_escape_string() blocks quotes but to me it seems to be allowing no quotes at all...

Am I correct?

Comment: [**`mysql_XXX` functions are deprecated**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

Comment: [This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Why not using for an int var just `$id = (int) $_GET['id']`?

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` should make SQL injection attacks less likely however, it is strongly advised that you use the MySQL database APIs that are not deprecated such as [MySQLi (MySQL Improved)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which have stronger security in place.

I also believe you are calling a non existent function where you assign the `$num` variable it should be `mysql_num_rows()` not `mysql_numrows`.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` puts the functions argument into a form that is usable **inside quotes** within SQL. They MUST be used. And they can always be used, even when dealing with numeric values.

Not using the quotes in sql prevents the security of escaping the string.